# cannot convert value of type "inout CGAffineTransform" to expected argument

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make the player change of direction while is in a path, the problem is that every time I run the app it pop out an error of "cannot convert value of type "inout CGAffineTransform" to expected argument..."

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    if gameStarted == false {

        gameStarted = true
        moveClockWise()
        movingClockWise = true


        var myCircle : CGMutablePath! = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let newDx = player.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let newDy = player.position.y - self.frame.height / 2
        let newRad = atan2(newDy, newDx)
        let newPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2) , radius: 170, startAngle: newRad, endAngle: newRad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

        var mirroring = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0) // flip horizontal
        var mirrorPath : CGMutablePath! = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let finalPath = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&mirroring)//Here it tells me the error
        {
            CGPathAddPath(mirrorPath, UnsafeMutablePointer($0), newPath.CGPath!)
        }

        let newFollow = SKAction.followPath(mirrorPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
        player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(newFollow).reversedAction(),withKey:"followPath")


   }else  {
        player.removeActionForKey("followPath")
    }

       }

func moveClockWise(){

    let dx = player.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy = player.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2) , radius: 170, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
    player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction(),withKey:"followPath")

}
```

Comment: Forget withUnsafeMutablePointer.  Try `CGPathAddPath(mirrorPath, &mirroring, newPath.CGPath!)`

Comment: now it tells me extra argument in call, and if I remove newPath.CGPath! it tells me in CGPathAddPath(mirrorPath, UnsafeMutablePointer($0), newPath.CGPath!) "ambiguos use of int()

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: I posted the suggested code.  Is that still giving you errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing your code to:

```
    var mirroring = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0) // flip horizontal
    var mirrorPath : CGMutablePath! = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddPath(mirrorPath, &mirroring, newPath.CGPath)

    let newFollow = SKAction.followPath(mirrorPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
    player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(newFollow).reversedAction(),withKey:"followPath")
```

---

From Apple's documentation [Interacting with C API's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17)

> Constant Pointers
>
> When a function is declared as taking a UnsafePointer argument,
>   it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer.
> - An UnsafePointer,
>     UnsafeMutablePointer, or AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer
>     value, which is converted to UnsafePointer if necessary.
> - A
>     String value, if Type is Int8 or UInt8. The string will automatically
>     be converted to UTF8 in a buffer, and a pointer to that buffer is
>     passed to the function.
> - An inout expression whose left-hand side
>     operand is of type Type, which is passed as a pointer to the address
>     of the left-hand side identifier.
> - A [Type] value, which is passed as a
>     pointer to the start of the array.

The 4th bullet is the one that tells us you can send `&mirroring` for the argument that is expecting `UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>`.

Comment: thanks vacawama!, can you help me in something else in my code?

Comment: I am trying to make that the player change to the opposite direction while is in a path. The problem is that my code isnt working of how I spected, when touches began the player dissapears. Can you help me to find a solution?

Comment: I think that is beyond the scope of this question and my ability at this time of night.  I suggest you post a follow up question to Stack Overflow.  State clearly what you want to happen, and what is happening.